# vary the number of elif statements in python bet list length in python

Tags: python, grasshopper

I'm trying to create a script that uses the if/elif/else structure, but I'd like it to expand and contract the elifs with the number of elements in a list.

The attempt below contains 5 elements (a-e), and gets sorted through five conditionals (if, elif, elif, elif, else).

Is there an elegant way to make this script work if I were to input the set (a-z), without needing to make several more elif?

```
Values = (0.1,0.12,0.3,0.8,0.802)
Categories = ("a","b","c","d","e")
MySizeType = []

for i in Values:
    if i < .2:
        MySizeType.append(Categories[0])
    elif i < .4:
        MySizeType.append(Categories[1])
    elif i < .6:
        MySizeType.append(Categories[2])
    elif i < .8:
        MySizeType.append(Categories[3])
    else:
        MySizeType.append(Categories[4])
```

Comment: Are these values always < 1?

Comment: Thanks everyone for the feedback. I was able to get the results I needed using the top comment. I also remapped the values to be 0<1, and created a dictionary with two variable inputs to allow varying lengths of input Categories.

Answer (score 3):

Expanding on my comment:

You can't dynamically build an if/elif structure, but you can accomplish the same logic with a loop and a dictionary that maps threshold values to categories. Something like this:

```
Values = (0.1, 0.12, 0.3, 0.8, 0.802)

# NB: Here we are taking advantage of the fact that in modern Python (3.7+),
# dictionaries preserve insert order. This was not the case for earlier
# versions of Python.
Categories = {
    0.2: "a",
    0.4: "b",
    0.6: "c",
    0.8: "d",
    "default": "e",
}

MySizeType = []

for i in Values:
    for threshold, category in Categories.items():
        if threshold == "default":
            continue

        if i < threshold:
            MySizeType.append(category)
            break
    else:
        MySizeType.append(Categories["default"])

print(MySizeType)
```

This will output...

```
['a', 'a', 'b', 'e', 'e']
```

...which appears correct for your sample data.

---

With a minor change to the data structures:

```
Categories = {
    0.2: "a",
    0.4: "b",
    0.6: "c",
    0.8: "d",
}
DefaultCategory = "e"
```

You could reduce that loop down to a single expression:

```
MySizeType = [
    next((cat[1] for cat in Categories.items() if v < cat[0]), DefaultCategory)
    for v in Values
]
```

---

@KellyBundy points out that my initial statement was not entirely accurate. Here's a solution in the spirit of their comment that uses [Jinja2](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/) to dynamically generate a chain if `elsif` statements:

```
import jinja2

Values = (0.1, 0.12, 0.3, 0.8, 0.802)
Categories = {
    0.2: "a",
    0.4: "b",
    0.6: "c",
    0.8: "d",
}
DefaultCategory = "e"
MySizeType = []

code = jinja2.Template(
    """
if False:
    pass
{% for threshold,category in categories.items() %}
elif i < {{threshold}}:
    MySizeType.append("{{category}}")
{% endfor %}
else:
    MySizeType.append(DefaultCategory)
"""
).render(categories=Categories)

blob = compile(code, "__generated__", "single")
for i in Values:
    exec(blob, globals(), locals())

print(MySizeType)
```

The output is the same as the earlier code.

For the record, don't do this.

Comment: A quick note: this will work because dictionary insertion order is maintained in Python 3.7+. _If_ an earlier version of Python is being used, this might not achieve the desired results. To prevent this you might just use a list of tuples.

Comment: I was noting that in the answer while you were leaving a comment :).

Comment: Either great minds think alike or small minds seldom differ.

Comment: Thankfully, this caveat should be less and less of an issue as time passes. Only out-of-support versions of Python *don't* preserve insertion order at this point, and there are far fewer reasons to stick with older 3.x releases than there were for clinging to 2.7 long after Python 3 had established itself.

Comment: *"You can't dynamically build an if/elif structure"* - Sure you can. Generate the code and `compile()` it.

Answer (score 1):

In this case, you can calculate the category. The formula I used assumed numbers are in range [0, 1), but you can adjust the formula to accomodate for negative numbers or numbers greater than or equal to 1.

```
Values = (0.1,0.12,0.3,0.8,0.802)
Categories = ("a","b","c","d","e")
MySizeType = []

for i in Values:
    category = int(i // 0.2)
    MySizeType.append(Categories[category])
```

Comment: This works but isn't terribly flexible if the thresholds are irregular.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest trying using [`bisect`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/bisect.html) which is part of standard library. For given sorted list it finds index (position) where to put certain element so it would remain sorted. Consider following simple example

```
import bisect
category = ["a", "b", "c", "d"]
value = [0.1, 0.3, 0.9]
for i in [0.0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 1.0]:
    pos = bisect.bisect_left(value, i)
    cat = category[pos]
    print("Element", i, "belongs to category", cat)
```

gives output

```
Element 0.0 belongs to category a
Element 0.1 belongs to category a
Element 0.2 belongs to category b
Element 0.3 belongs to category b
Element 0.4 belongs to category c
Element 0.5 belongs to category c
Element 0.6 belongs to category c
Element 0.7 belongs to category c
Element 0.8 belongs to category c
Element 0.9 belongs to category c
Element 1.0 belongs to category d
```

Observe that categories has one more element that value, as 3 cuts result in 4 parts. Keep in mind that `value` list **must** be sorted. Depending on how you would treat values equal to threshold you might choose between `bisect.bisect_left` and `bisect.bisect_right`.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid the proliferation of `elif` you should place the thresholds of your categories in a list.  This will allow you to find the index of the appropriate category by searching for the first threshold value that is larger or equal to each input value.

You can use the `next()` function to perform this search sequentially or, if you have a very large list of categories, a binary search (using bisect):

```
Values = (0.1, 0.12, 0.3, 0.8, 0.802)

Categories = ("a","b","c","d","e")
breaks     = [.2, .4, .6, .8, 1.0 ] # threshold values for category

# SEQUENTIAL SEARCH:

MySizeType = [ Categories[next(i for i,b in enumerate(breaks) if b>=v)]
               for v in Values ]

print(MySizeType)
['a', 'a', 'b', 'd', 'e']


# BINARY SEARCH:
                          
from bisect import bisect_right
MySizeType = [ Categories[bisect_right(breaks,v)] for v in Values ]

print(MySizeType)
['a', 'a', 'b', 'd', 'e']
```

Answer (score -1):

`Categories` is indexed by integer values. Assuming you know the distribution of valid values, you could normalize those values to the category index. If the value range is `[0, 1)`, you could multiply by the length of the category array and its floor integer value is the index.

```
Values = (0.1,0.12,0.3,0.8,0.802)
Categories = ("a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i") # got bored...
MySizeType = [Categories[int(value * len(Categories))]
        for value in Values]
print(f"For Categories {Categories}:")
for v,s in zip(Values, MySizeType):
    print(f"{v} --> {s}")
```

Output

```
For Categories ('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i'):
0.1 --> a
0.12 --> b
0.3 --> c
0.8 --> h
0.802 --> h
```

Comment: I loved the simplicity of this option. My particular usage made using integers impossible however, so I tried something else. However, its a strategy I may use for another project; thanks!